# Prove $x \in f^{-1}(C) \iff f(x) \in C$ where $f: X \to Y$ is a function and $A \subseteq X, \ C \subseteq Y$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I have a question about the red line below. Is it correct? If it's correct, does the whole proof hold? Thank you.

Suppose $x \in f^{-1}(C).$ By definition of $f, \ x \in X \implies f(x) \in C.$ But $f^{-1}(C) \subseteq X$ and so $x \in f^{-1}(C) \implies f(x) \in C$. Now assume $f(x) \in C. \ \color{red}{\text{Since $f(x)$ is defined, there must be $x \in X$ that maps to this $f(x)$}}.$ Then by definition of $f^{-1}(C)$, it follows that $x \in f^{-1}(C)$.

edit:

The given definition of preimage in the book is as follows

Let $f: A \to B$ be a function. Let $T \subseteq B$. Then the preimage of $T$ under $f$ is $f^{-1}(T) = \{x \in A: f(x) \in T\}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since $f(x)$ is defined, there must be $x \in X$ that maps to this $f(x)$

Is the $x$ in the first part of the sentence (“Since $f(x)$ is defined”) the same $x$ that appears in the second part of the sentence? (“there must be $x \in X$ ...”)?

- If not, it needs to have a new name, like $x'$.  Then you're saying that there exists $x' \in X$ such that $f(x') = f(x)$.  Which is at least grammatically correct.
- If so, then you don't need to assert its existence.  The $x$ at the start of the paragraph is already supposed to be an element of $f^{-1}(C)$.

My main question is why are you proving this?  Most texts I am familiar with *define* $f^{-1}(C)$ to be the set of all $x \in X$ such that $f(x) \in C$.  If that's the same definition you're working with, then there's nothing to prove.

Comment: Madden and Aubrey have this proof in their book "An Introduction to Proof through Real Analysis". I couldn't make sense of the proof in the book so I tried rewriting it. Making a distinction between $x$ and $x'$ actually answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: I have a follow-up question: if $f(x')$ is defined and is in the range of $f$, then is it possible for the domain of $f$ to have no $x$ that corresponds to $f(x')$? In other words, must every image have a pre-image under a function? Why? This is somehow not obvious to me. Thanks.

Comment: I can't really answer that without knowing Madden and Aubrey's definition of $f^{-1}(C)$. Can you add it to the question?

Comment: I have updated my OP. Consider the function $f: A \to B$ and $T \subseteq B.$ Then $ f^{-1}(T) = \{x \in A: f(x) \in T\}$ which is equivalent to $s \in f^{-1}(T) \iff f(s) \in T$. The direction where $s \in f^{-1}(T) \implies f(s) \in T$ is obviously by definition of $f^{-1}(T).$ I am having difficulty with the converse implication. How do we jump from "$x \in A$ such that $f(x) \in T$" to " $f(s) \in T \implies s \in f^{-1}(T)$"? It's kind of a semantic question I am stuck on.

Comment: OK, answer to your followup question: $f(x')$ is “defined” if and only if $x'$ is in the domain of $f$.  So there is at least one $x$ in the domain of $f$ that corresponds to $f(x')$—$x'$ itself.  So yes, every image has a nonempty pre-image, including at least what it is the image of.

Comment: I checked out the book.  Are you looking at Theorem 12.2.1, statement 2?  The authors confess that this statement and the one before it in the list are “restatements of the definition.”  I'm not sure I see the value of trying to prove them, since they are tautologies.  If something satisfies the definition of a term, we can apply that term to it.  if something is called by a term, then it satisfies the definition.